# How can I check if a string contains a specific charater in Regex?

Tags: regex

How can I check if a string contains at any position one or more '/' character(s) in Regex?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should indicate which programming language you're talking about. The answer depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to check to see if a string has '/' in it? If so, you might consider using what's probably a built-in method in whatever language you're writing your code in:

```
bool containsSlash = myString.IndexOf('/') >= 0;
```

Otherwise, you can "escape" the character by using the following notation;

```
\/
```

Answer (score 2):

escape it with a backslash, e.g.
/

Answer (score 1):

By escaping it with a \ (backslash).

Answer (score 1):

Regex APIs tend to be implementation specific so we'll need to know what language / tool you are using to give a 100% correct answer.  But the quick one is simply

```
.*\/.*
```

However for this type of question, it's much more efficient to use a string searching API.  Regex's are best at matching patterns.  Filtering out for a single character is best done through IndexOf or a similar function.

Comment: the leading and trailing .* will not be necessary most of the time :)

Comment: That depends if your engine is matching from the start of the line or "searching" the text. The .* after shouldn't matter though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regexp for this, there are far cheaper ways to scan for a character.  If you are using `c` I suggest you use `strrchr`.  From the manpage:

```
char * strrchr(const char *s, int c);
```

> The strrchr() function locates the
>   last occurrence of c (converted to a
>       char) in the string s.  If c is `\0', strrchr() locates the
>   terminating`
>   \0'.

For example:

```
bool contains(char c, char* myString) {
  return 0 != strrchr(myString, c);
}

contains("alex", 'x'); // returns true
contains("woo\\123", '\\'); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

In c#:

```
String sss = "<your string>";
Regex re1 = new Regex(@".*/.*");

if (re1.IsMatch(sss)) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `\/+`. However it depends on engine.

Comment: The + isn't necessary for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it to you in pseudo-Perl because you didn't ask for anything specific.

```
$has_slash = 0;
# first slash starts regex
# backslash escape the next slash
# because it is escaped, we're looking for this as a literal slash
# end the regex pattern with the final slash
if ($string =~ /\//) {
    $has_slash = 1;
}
```